# Prove that $\sum_{i=0}^{50} {50 \choose i}^2 = {100 \choose 50}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> Prove that $$\sum_{i=0}^{50} {50 \choose i}^2 = {100 \choose 50}$$

---

I tried writing the following but did not get anywhere.

$$ {50 \choose 0} {50 \choose50} + {50 \choose 1} {50 \choose49} + \dots + {50 \choose 50} {50 \choose 0} $$

I even thought about pairing the $n$-th term and the respective $51$st term and taking $2$ common (except for $50 \choose 25$, which is alone). I am too scared to take the LCM. Is there any special property that I am unaware of?

To be honest, I don't have any idea from where to even start.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).

Comment: Consider choosing $50$ objects out of $100$, which is what the right side is counting. Now, fix a split of the $100$ objects into two sets of $50$ each. Consider selecting the $50$ objects by selecting $k$ from the first set and $50-k$ from the second. Note that the number of ways to do that is $\binom{50}{k}\binom{50}{50-k}$.

Comment: @NDB 's answer is the best (most natural and informative) way to do this. But if you can't see that, induction is always a good approach for these types of question.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe and NDB that was helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution by double counting can be given as noted in the above comment. Another standard algebraic approach (which is the same in essence) but it is a cute idea to use polynomials for those kinds of things is the following.

Consider the polynomial:

$$(x+1)^{100}$$

In view of Newton the coefficient of $x^{50}$ when expanding the above polynomial is $\binom{100}{50}$ . On the other hand you can expand it in a different way, one may write:

$$ (x+1)^{100} = (x+1)^{50}(x+1)^{50} $$

And expand after.Then the coefficient of $x^{50}$ by polynomial multiplication and using the binomial must be:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{50} \binom{50}{i} \binom{50}{50-i} = \sum_{i=0}^{50} \binom{50}{i}^2 $$

but these two coefficients must be the same and the claim follows.

Comment: I think you should delete this answer because this post: 1) is a FAQ which already received many answers. See e.g. [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860347) or [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148583). 2) goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.